# How to change the number of upgradeDomainCount on an existing cloud service in azure?

Tags: azure

The number of upgrade domains in a service are 5 by default and that's what got deployed the first time I deployed my service. Now if I try to do an upgrade and change the upgradeDomainCount to say 3, I get an error:  Set-AzureDeployment : BadRequest : The number of upgrade domains in the service upgrade package for role 'foo' differs from the number specified in the currently deployed service. The currently deployed service specifies 5 upgrade  domains while the upgrade package specifies 3 upgrade domains.

Is there a flag to force the upgrade?

-Thanks

Comment: You'll likely need to do a new deploy instead of an in-place upgrade. This makes sense since changing the number of upgrade domains could also impact fault domain distribution and thus require some of the role instances to need to be re-provisioned.

Comment: Deleting the existing (prod) deployment and a new deployment worked for me.

Comment: For future me figuring out how to change the upgradeDomainCount in the first place: It's an attribute in the cloud service's csdef file.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround using the (non-prod) staging slot.

1. Delete staging slot if it has already been deployed to
2. Deploy your cloud service to staging slot using the new `upgradeDomainCount` setting
3. Switch staging slot with production slot

Answer (score -1):

Stop the cloud service, re-deploy and then Start it again.

Edit: by redeploy, I mean re-deploy the cloud service with the new upgrade domain count. My answer basically says, you cannot change this setting on a running service (at the time of the answer).

Comment: This results in the same error "Deployment could not be updated". Maybe specify what you mean by "re-deploy".